# Comparison between two routes

Tags: c#, algorithm, gps, compare

I am working on Gps tracking.

I have two routes (2 paths consisting of points, with latitude/longtitute):

- the planned route;
- the actual route which the driver has traveled.

I want to compare if both are the same or not. Can anybody suggest which approach I should use?

Comment: Okay, so I am explaining it to you. Let suppose there are paths path1 & path2 from source A to destination B and my friend wants to travel A to B. Assume that I have Coordinates of path1 and asked my friend to choose path1 but he used path2 and he gives me the coordinates of the path which he chose mean path2. So I have the coordinates of both paths path1 which I proposed to him and path2 which he used now I want to compare those paths programmatically either they are the same or not (same means either he used the same path which I proposed to him or not). Do you understand the problem now?

Comment: I guess the number of points is different? I'd try hit-test approach, converting first path (line) into a polygon with big enough tolerance and then just check if all points of second path are inside this polygon.